# One unix socket file has two inodes, why?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I employ the command `lsof -c sshd`, generating the ensuing output:\

```
command  pid    node    name

sshd     214812 563464 /path/to/ssh-agent
```

Following this, I run `ls -inum /path/to/ssh-agent` and acquire:\

`3538970 /path/to/ssh-agent`

We observe the identical socket file /path/to/ssh-agent, yet encounter disparate inodes (numbers).
Upon further examination, I ascertain that one of the above stems from `task->fdt->fd[i]->file->f_inode->i_ino`, which points to a `/UNIX-STREAM` file (not the actual agent file), while the other originates from `task->fdt->fd[i]->file->private_data->path.dentry->d_node->i_ino`.\

Nonetheless, the question arises: why are two inodes necessitated for a single Unix socket?